# Changes in LiveData not visible in @Composable through observeAsState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

It seems I am making the mistake in observing `LiveData` and can't seem to find where is the error.

This is the code for `@Composable`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShowAppsScreen2(
    viewModel: SharedViewModel
) {

    val text: String by viewModel.name.observeAsState(initial = "")

    Log.d("ShowAppsScreen2", "ShowAppsScreen2: text = $text.")

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(1f)
        .background(color = Color.Red)) {
        Text("TEXT: $text")
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.fetchName("Eva")
    }

}
```

And this is the code for `SharedViewModel`:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    //...
) ViewModel() {

    private val _name: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val name: LiveData<String> = _name

    fun fetchName(someName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(500)
            Log.d(TAG, "setName: $someName")
            _name.postValue(someName)
        }
    }    

}
```

First, I see red screen as set in my `@Composable` with `Text` having text ***"TEXT:"*** as expected. After that, I only see white screen as though some error occurred and screen is not re-rendered.

In log I get this:

> ```
> D ShowAppsScreen2: ShowAppsScreen2: text = . 
> D ShowAppsScreen2: ShowAppsScreen2: text = . 
> D ShowAppsScreen2: ShowAppsScreen2: text = . 
> D SharedViewModel: setName: Eva
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this code works fine to me, e.g. `D/ShowAppsScreen2: ShowAppsScreen2: text = .; D/SharedViewModel: setName: Eva; D/ShowAppsScreen2: ShowAppsScreen2: text = Eva.` Have not idea how can it become white. Sure that's all code related to this question?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the all code related to this question. And that, to be honest, pisses me off, because I can't see what is wrong with it or what is hidden somewhere else. I will start by rewriting Composable and ViewModel from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine. I've made a mistake in handling Navigation (don't ask!), but this code can stay here as a reference of (I hope) proper way of dealing with initial actions in `@Composable` functions.